# After using vite+vue3 to build the project and importing roslibjs, an error is reported

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, ros, vite

I use vue3, when I create a project with **vite**, I import the [roslibjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/roslib) library and get an error using one of the functions, as shown below. But when I try to use vuecli to create a project, after importing the same library, everything is fine.
[image]

```
// vite created 'vite-app' project
npm init vite@latest
cd vite-app
npm instal --save roslib
// vuecli created 'vuecli-app' project
vue create vuecli-app
cd vuecli-app
npm install --save roslib
```

```html
<script setup>
import ROSLIB from "roslib";
let ws_address = '127.0.0.1:9090'
let connected = false;
const ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
    url: ws_address,
})
const connect = () => {
    ros.on("connection", () => {
        connected = true;
        console.log("Connected!");
    });
    ros.on("error", (error) => {
        console.log("Error connecting to websocket server: ", error);
    });
    ros.on("close", () => {
        connected = false;
        console.log("Connection to websocket server closed.");
    });
}
const disconnect = () => {
    ros.close();
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <p class="text-success" v-if="connected">Connected!</p>
        <p class="text-danger" v-else>Not connected!</p>
  
        <input type="text" v-model="ws_address" />
        <br />
        <button @click="disconnect" class="btn btn-danger" v-if="connected">Disconnect!</button>
        <button @click="connect" class="btn btn-success" v-else>Connect!</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what Vue CLI + Webpack does differently for `roslib` to work in the browser.

However, in the browser, you should use the pre-built versions of `roslib` (where the Node-specific constructs are transpiled away) per the [docs](http://robotwebtools.org/jsdoc/roslibjs/current/global.html#ROSLIB):

> If you use roslib in a browser, all the classes will be exported to a global variable called ROSLIB. If you use nodejs, this is the variable you get when you require('roslib')

Import the `roslib/build/roslib.js` script, which sets `window.ROSLIB`:

```html
<script setup>
import 'roslib/build/roslib';

const ros = new window.ROSLIB.Ros({
  url: ws_address,
});
⋮
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-roslib?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FRoslibDemo.vue)

Comment: Thinks, Import the `roslib/build/roslib.js` script solved my problem but I want to know why vite and vuecli deal with roslibjs in different ways of importing and What are the benefits of window.ROSLIB